# How do I fix a "Can't access Dropbox folder" error?

Tags: dropbox, inotify

I'm having a rather strange problem with Dropbox that started a few weeks ago.

Dropbox will stop syncing with the message "Can't access Dropbox folder", and refuse to sync until I reboot.

I've tried restarting Dropbox and logging out, but nothing I seem to do will allow it to sync again short of a reboot.

This is not a permissions problem, as the permissions don't change when I suddenly lose access.

I've checked lsof for anything related to dropbox that might still be hanging on when I stop it. As far as I can tell nothing else other than Dropbox is accessing it's folders when this happens.

Comment: I believe there was a recent kernel update that fixed it for good. bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1101666

Answer (score 56, accepted):

if you put these in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 1048576
fs.inotify.max_user_instances = 256
```

it will fix the issue. You may have to run `sudo sysctl -p` for these settings to take effect.

Alternatively, if you are not interested in making these settings permanent, you may try the following commands...

```
sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_instances=256
sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=1048576
```

In this case the settings will be lost after a reboot.

The problem is that the system has run out of inotify instances. You can check your syslog  (e.g. by using `tail -f /var/log/syslog`) and if you see...

> tail: inotify cannot be used, reverting to polling: Too many open file

then you know this is your issue. For me it was nepomuk.

Comment: Interesting. I'm seeing dovecot complaining: lister dovecot: imap(craig): Warning: Inotify instance limit for user 1000 (UID craig) exceeded, disabling. Increase /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances. Will add and see if that makes the problem disappear. Thank you!

Comment: Going to accept this answer for now, as it makes the most sense. Will check back if I run into it again. Thank you!

Comment: I had the exact same problem on a brand new installation of Ubuntu 12.10 with default settings. Increasing max_user_instances as described here solved the problem.

Comment: For Ubuntu, `sudo echo 256 > /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances` gives a permission denied error. `sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_instances=256` should be used instead.

Comment: I can confirm that this fixes the problem for me (Ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: Ubuntu 12.10 here. Fixed the problem for me as well!

Comment: Just wanted to confirm that this fix worked for Ubuntu 16.04. I had no issues up until yesterday with Dropbox and even went as far as changing my password to see if that would work and it did not. I applied this fix and now it's syncing everything that wasn't from before.

Comment: You need to run `sudo sysctl -p` for the changes to take effect.

Comment: This fix seems to still work on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I can confirm that this fixed the error.

Answer (score 1):

The fs.inotify.max_user_instances=256 fixed my immediate "Can't access dropbox folder" problem (Ubuntu 12.04).

It also cleared up an odd behavior I'd noticed, where the dropbox systray icon continually indicated file activity:  The arrow circles cycling continually, though nothing was changing in my dropbox, and the "recently changed files" list remained unchanged.

A few moments after I changed fs.inotify.max_user_instances=256, the pointless cycling stopped.

Answer (score -1):

In one of the forums, someone mentioned it is due to inotify. They have this solution/workaround.

- disable desktop search (in kde nepomuk+tracker, in gnome tracker)
- reboot (logout didn't help)

Comment: I'm not running tracker as far as I know. Is there a particular process I should be looking for?

Answer (score -1):

This usually happens because sysctrl has run out of inotify instances. The following 2 commands will normally fix the issue.

```
sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=1048576
sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_instances=256
```

Comment: Welcome to ask ubuntu could you elaborate on your answer a little more please so folk know what you are doing here